# Extract part of a string of each item in a list

Tags: json, ansible

I have a list like this:

```yaml
- my name is 'Andi', nice to meet you
- hello my name is 'Bella', hi!
- this is 'Cain'
```

I want to parse string after `is` in every row.
My expected output:

```yaml
- Andi
- Bella 
- Cain
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [`map`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#jinja-filters.map) a filter on each item of a list.
And to extract some text, you can use the [`regex_search` filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#searching-strings-with-regular-expressions).

Which gives a task like:

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: >-
      {{
        sentences | map("regex_search", "is '(.*)'", "\1") | flatten
      }}
  vars:
    sentences:
      - my name is 'Andi', nice to meet you
      - hello my name is 'Bella', hi!
      - this is 'Cain'
```

And yields:

```yaml
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg:
  - Andi
  - Bella
  - Cain
```